# Webscrape / Next page clicking not possible

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to get the next site eg. on this site:
https://www.11880.com/suche/Naturpark/deutschland

```
<div class="next">
   <form class="link-form" action="https://www.11880.com/form" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="source" value="*JSPPyTNQ4Hl4n6FJKGEcgCWqLzgK2zccsymE3agiLSMAKNMw9kRza81Id4CrUpZ08MJMZZgtfLcy7UQJ5Y8LxQ">
        <button class="link icon-right" title="Zur nächsten Seite" data-page="1" type="submit">
        </button>
   </form>
</div>
```

I tried to click the element with these statements :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="searchresultlist"]/div/div[1]/div[4]').click()
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("link icon-right").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[title^='4G Signal quality']")
```

With the first line I get this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message:
> element click intercepted: Element ... is not
> clickable at point (861, 949). Other element would receive the  click:
>
> ...

With the second line as try I get this error:
(obviously more the 1 element found with the class "link icon-right")

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Polzi\Documents\DEV\Fiverr\papillion\search11880.py", line 80, in <module>
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name("link icon-right").click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

And with the third line as try I get this error:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable at point (566, 919). Other element would receive the click: ...
(Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.106)

```
Any ideas how i can get this page right element clicked?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "next page" button appears on the bottom of the web page. You have to scroll to that element before clicking on it.
Like the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)

next_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".next")
actions.move_to_element(next_btn).perform()
next_btn.click()
```

**UPD**
If clicking on the "next button" is intercepted by the cookie-bar element you can close it before clicking on the next page button by

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="btn btn-close-cookiebar"]').click()
```

or you can click on the "next page button" with JavaScript instead of clicking it with driver, like this:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_btn)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - but also with your code i still get this error message: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="next">...</div> is not clickable at point (566, 914). Other element would receive the click: <section class="cookie-bar">...</section>
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.106)`

Comment: Thanks again - now it seems to work - has to change it from elements to element and put the whole thing in a try/except (cause otherwise with elements i got an error and during the further scraping it seems that the cookiebar to close is not allways available)

Comment: btw: How are you able to find such things "The "next page" button appears on the bottom of the web page. You have to scroll to that element before clicking on it." Where do you see this in the the inspect-code?

Comment: or also this thing: "If clicking on the "next button" is intercepted by the cookie-bar element you can close it before clicking on the next page button by"

Comment: You are right about the `find_elements`, thanks! You also could use `find_elements` there and then validate if the list is non-empty then click on the first element in that list instead of using the try-catch

Comment: As about the second question: you can see it visually. The next page button is not presented when the page is opened, you need to scroll to see it. This is what you perform with Selenium too

Comment: You wrote me that this was the issue, the cookie-bar element intercepted the click :)